# vbKeySpace and automation error

Tags: excel, key, runtime-error, vba

I have a strange issue. Below is my code.

In short it checks if certain key was pressed on keyboard. If yes it runs 2 subroutines and sets focus on button called `diesel`. I wanted to add another Key -> Space (vbKeySpace). After adding it I receive: runtime error -2147417848 (80010108) automation error.

I have no idea how to cope with it...

```
Private Sub Dostawcy_listbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Select Case KeyCode

'Enter = wstaw dane klienta
Case vbKeyReturn, vbKeySpace
    dane_dostawcy
    turn_on
    diesel.SetFocus

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Try changing the Select case statement to an If to see if that solves the problem:

```
If (KeyCode = vbKeyReturn) or (KwyCode = vbKeySpace) then
etc.
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, there might be more complicated things going on. Like code that you have running in the KeyUp event. Or the delay in the two subroutines you call is messing something up. Or the actions inside those routines. You can also try to comment out the subroutines one by one to try and isolate the problem.